# Google Analytics - How I can do tracking to different users?

Tags: javascript, drupal, google-analytics

I have to create 3 profiles for 3 types of users who have the same role in Drupal. But according to the type of user is the type of profile, so I have no idea as to edit the script.

Comment: Don't worry about your English, someone can clean that up. That said, you really need to provide more details and possibly some samples of what you've tried.

Comment: You have three different user Roles in Drupal? And you want to report a user's Role to Google Analytics so you can track usage by Role? How do profiles fit into the equation?

Comment: I have installed the google analytics module with the default options, but I need something more advanced. Each authenticated user has an associated trade (only 3 types) so I have to relate the trade with some google analytics profile.

Comment: So you need to use a different Google Analytical tracking code depending on the user's role? For that you would need to write your own code. Check the current user's role and output the appropriate script tag. You could hack that into a theme or make your own module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Google Analytics](https://drupal.org/project/google_analytics) module to add Google's tracking JavaScript to your pages. You can also configure the module to send custom variables to Google Analytics. For example, to send the user's roles:

```
Slot:  1
Name:  Role
Value: [user-role-names]
Scope: Visitor
```

Comment: I have installed the google analytics module with the default options, but I need something more advanced. Each authenticated user has an associated trade (only 3 types) so I have to relate the trade with some google analytics profile.